# Adafruit 16x2 display with keypad not working accepting button input on RasPi B+ 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, adafruit

I am currently working on a school project and using the RasPi B+ 3 and the Adafruit 16x2 display with keypad.

I'm using these to display the names and scores of the 2 players, playing on the air hockey table. Who have to enter their names using the 5 buttons (up, down, right, left, select) the up and down control the character: if up is pressed change A to B, B to C if pressed again. If down is pressed change C to B, B to A if pressed again. The right and left are to control the place of the character you are changing: if left is pressed move character to the left and if right is pressed move to the character to the right.

**The problem I have is that none of the above options seems to work, the LCD  will only light up when the code is started, but no characters appear on the LCD**

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

I'm using python3

This is my code:

```
import time
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD


# Initialize the LCD using the pins
lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCDPlate()

button_1 = (LCD.SELECT, 'Select', (1,1,1))
button_2 = (LCD.LEFT,   'Left'  , (1,0,0))
button_3 = (LCD.UP,     'Up'    , (1,0,1))
button_4 = (LCD.DOWN,   'Down'  , (1,1,0))
button_5 = (LCD.RIGHT,  'Right' , (1,0,1))

while cycle == true:
    x = 65
    y = 65
    part = 1
    while True:
#Part 1
#This part is for the name of player1
    if part == 1:
        if lcd.is_pressed(button_1):
            part += 1
            #To continue to part2
        if lcd.is_pressed(button_3):

            lcd.noblink
            x += 1
            cc=ord(x)
            x_2 = cc

            if x_2 > 90:
                x_2 -= 25
            #For moving from Z to A
            lcd.message(char(x_2))
            #moving the characters up 1 (A, B, C....)
        if lcd.is_pressed(button_4):

            lcd.noblink
            x -= 1
            cc=ord(x)
            x_2 = cc

            if x_2 < 65:
                x_2 += 25

                #For moving from A to Z
            lcd.message(char(x_2))
        #moving the characters down 1 Z, X, Y....)
        if lcd.is_pressed(button_2):
            remove(x_2)
            lcd.move_left
            x = 65
            #moving the editable character to the left
        if lcd.is_pressed(button_5):
            append(x_2)
            lcd.move_right
            x = 65

            #moving the editable character to the right
#Part 2
#This part is for the name of player2           
    if part == 2:
        if lcd.is_pressed(button_1):
            part += 1
            #To continue to the next part (visualis the names)
        if lcd.is_pressed(button_3):

            lcd.noblink
            y += 1
            cc=ord(y)
            y_2 = cc

            if y_2 > 90:
                y_2 -= 25
                #For moving from Z to A
            lcd.message(char(y_2))
            #moving the characters up 1 (A, B, C....)
        if lcd.is_pressed(button_4):

            lcd.noblink
            y -= 1
            cc=ord(y)
            y_2 = cc

            if y_2 < 65:
                y_2 += 25
                #For moving from A to Z 
            lcd.message(char(y_2))
            #moving the characters down 1 (Z, X, Y....)
        if lcd.is_pressed(button_2):
            remove(y_2)
            lcd.move_left
            y = 65
            #moving the editable character to the left 
        if lcd.is_pressed(button_5):
            append(y_2)
            lcd.move_right
            y = 65
            #moving the editable character to the right
#Part 3
#This part is for displaying the first 7 Characters of the names   (16/2=8  8-1=7 (this is for the spacing between the names) )
    if part == 3:
        # here must go the array to display the first and the second name
```

Comment: Do you have a trimpot on your 16x2 LCD? usually should be there, and if it is, move it to change the contrast, sometimes the info is already there. Otherwise could be a hardware problem. Seen that many times...

Comment: I don't think it's the contrast or hardware, because the "pre-installed" code I got from the Adafruit website works great. I only have this problem since I got to my code. And what is even worse is that the code suddenly won't run at all. I think the error was "Unable to find Adafruit_CharLCD" even though it is in the same map as the pre-installed stuff...